# How can I make this number input accept commas?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a input in a website, the type of this input is number. Because of this I can't enter a comma which is needed.

Can some one teach me how I can make my input number and comma only?

This is the input I have ATM:

```
Bedrag: <input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="goed_doel_bedrag" id="goed_doel_bedrag" placeholder="Vul hier het bedrag in">
```

This needs to be a decimal point comma (not thousand).

Comment: When you use HTML5 input types, you're asking the browser to take control over it, you don't have detailed control.

Comment: Yes... The step attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the Input I have now to a other thing which is ableto got comma and number only

Comment: Are you using comma as a decimal separator or a thousand separator?

Comment: decimal like with €5,63

Comment: You can use `oninput` and edit the entered value with RegExp if needed.

Comment: do you have a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in this type of job you should use JS and/or jQuery.

First create a function:

```
function commaOnly(input){ 

    var value = input.val();
    var values = value.split("");
    var update = "";
    var transition = "";

    var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
    var finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;

    for(id in values){           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!=''){
            transition+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
            if(finalExpression.test(transition) == true){
                update+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
            }
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

This will turn dots into commas and accepts only one comma. This way if someone presses the dot, that's going to be changed to a comma instead of blocking his input.

Then assign that function to your input:

```
$('#goed_doel_bedrag').keyup(function (e) {
  commaOnly($(this));
});
```

And change to input type `text`:

```
<input type="text" step="any" min="0" name="goed_doel_bedrag" id="goed_doel_bedrag" placeholder="Vul hier het bedrag in">
```

Fiddle here: [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w02wvqjw/)

Comment: Your welcome. For more data about using `text` instead of `number` as input, please see Jukka K. Korpela answer.

Answer (score 4):

An `input` element with `type=number` accepts commas if the user interface provided by the implementation is written or configured to accept localized input that uses commas in numbers. This is determined by browser and/or system settings, and you cannot set in your code.

The conclusion is that such elements are useful only when you are willing to accept the variation in user interfaces. Each user can input numbers in a manner dictated by his browsing environment, and the browser is expected to canonicalize it to a specific internal format (e.g. converting 5,63 to 5.63 if the locale uses the comma as decimal separator).

If you don’t want that, you need to use other methods, such as `type=text`.